# loop run a robotium case with different inputs

Tags: android, automation, robotium

I want to run the case with Robotium with different input parameters. for example, I want to test the browser open a web page, and there are many websites.

At the beginning, I want to use a loop in the case, but the case cannot go on, if the browser crash caused by one site.

Is there any solution for this requirement? Thanks ~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop your tests with different params by using command line and adb.

1. You could store a lot of xml files with input parameters on your PC and copy them by using adb (see [Using adb To Copy Files To / From Your Android Device](http://log.amitshah.net/2012/05/using-adb-to-copy-files-to-from-your-android-device/)); then parse it during tests
2. You could use batch file to run tests cyclically. Even if your test fails, the following test will start (your browser will be opened again). Use adb command to run test:

   adb shell am instrument -w your.package.in.test.project/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

Note: to use this command, you need apk files of both application and test to be installed on the device. Or you need to build apk files (for example, with maven) and then you can install it without Eclipse.

Hope, it helps.